# unordered_map and unordered_set are working differently in MSVC++ and G++ compilers

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, g++

unordered_map and unordered_set are working differently in MSVC++ and G++ compilers.
The insertion order is maintained properly in MSVC++ but not in g++

```
unordered_set<char> uset;
uset.emplace('b');
uset.emplace('a');
uset.emplace('d');
uset.emplace('c');
for (auto it : uset) {
    cout << it << " ";
}
```

The above code prints b a d c on windows with MSVC++ where as prints c d b a on linux using GCC(g++).
Which is correct?
I am a windows dev for long time, just surprised looking at results on linux.

Comment: The `unordered` part of the name tells that that there is no guaranteed order of the elements.

Comment: Technically, an implementation would be allowed to produce different results each time you run the program. You can be sure each element appears exactly once, and that the order is consistent for a given execution of the program but expecting anything beyond that is an error.

Comment: Correction: insertion order is maintained properly => [traversal order happens to be the same as insertion order in some small test cases](https://godbolt.org/z/3x8ebT3d1).

Answer (score 5):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set , the order depends on the hash function, that might be different in different implementations.

Comment: And considering the programmer can specify the hash function either all bets are off with respect to regularity because they could change the function at any compile, or you have the solution to the asker's problem: Provide a custom hash function that you guarantee produces the same results on all targets.